# Someone is going to get fired for this!

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

A fire has erupted in at a house.  When the fire department arrives three people, Riley, Billy, and Bob, are all trapped inside the house.  Riley is conscious and able to call out of a window for help, but by then Billy and Bob are both alive but unconscious and in no condition to rescue themselves.

The fireman use a ladder to help Riley out of the home, but no one else is seen to leave the house.  When asked if they would send a firemen into the home to rescue anyone else the chief replies he didn't see any reason to do so.  This is despite his being aware of Billy and Bob's current situation.

All people are human, and the fire is still out of control and a danger to anyone in the house.  So why aren't they doing anything to help anyone else?

Hint:

> Billy and bob were ultimately rescued

Comment: What's the best way to go about answering these? Should I put any idea in its own post/answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Billy and Bob:

> are unborn twins and Riley is their pregnant mother.  When Riley was rescued, Billy and Bob were as well.

Answer (score 0):

Billy and Bob didn't need rescuing because

> They were in a bath house. They were surrounded/partially submerged in water, so they weren't at risk of the fire. (If it helps alleviate drowning risk, they also dutifully swim wearing full scuba gear at all time).

Comment: How does that fit with them being "alive but unconscious"?

Comment: They were passed out in the pool after having one too many cocktails